# Select top 1 subquery with parameters (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am removing a user function which finds shows item prices based on configurations but the function is too slow.
Therefore I'm trying to write a query to do the same.  This query finds the latest price that matches the required criteria

This is kind of what I'm going for but I cannot figure out how to handle this requirement correctly:

(Intellisesnse says s.inventdimid does not exist in the h subquery)

```
SELECT s.salesid
    ,s.itemid
    ,h.price
FROM salesline s
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 p.price
        ,p.itemid
        ,p.dataareaid
        ,l.inventdimid
    FROM inventitemprice p
    JOIN inventdim d ON d.dataareaid = p.dataareaid
        AND d.inventdimid = p.inventdimid
    JOIN inventdim l ON l.dataareaid = p.dataareaid
        AND (
            l.configid = d.configid
            OR d.configid = ''
            )
        AND (
            l.inventcolorid = d.inventcolorid
            OR d.inventcolorid = ''
            )
        AND (
            l.inventsizeid = d.inventsizeid
            OR d.inventsizeid = ''
            )
        AND (
            l.inventstyleid = d.inventstyleid
            OR d.inventstyleid = ''
            )
        AND (p.ACTIVATIONDATE < getdate())
        AND l.inventsiteid = d.inventsiteid
    WHERE pricetype = 0
        AND l.inventdimid = s.inventdimid /* <========= */
        AND p.dataareaid = 'lkc'
    ORDER BY activationdate DESC
        ,d.configid DESC
        ,d.inventcolorid DESC
        ,d.INVENTSIZEID DESC
        ,d.inventstyleid DESC
    ) AS h ON h.itemid = s.itemid
    AND h.DATAAREAID = s.DATAAREAID
    AND h.INVENTDIMID = s.inventdimid
WHERE s.dataareaid = 'lkc'
    AND s.SALESSTATUS = 1
```

What would be the appropriate method for querying this?

Comment: Use an `OUTER APPLY` not a `LEFT JOIN`. Subqueries in a `JOIN` must be a lateral sub query; you cannot reference columns outside of the subquery's scope in the subquery itself. Subqueries inside an `APPLY` are correlated and *can* reference columns outside of the subquery's scope.

Comment: @Larnu Perfect!  I've never heard of OUTER APPLY statement but it works as needed.  Took me a minute to figure out why the ON statement wasn't working but I figured it out